# embed jquery->listener in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

Basicly, while user change any input, javascript have to read all inputs at the same time...
This jquery event handler/listener works perfect as it is ...

```
$("input").change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

But when i call this jquery handler in an javascript function manually. It does not execute alert, after a change

```
    <button onclick="cik()"></button>

<script>
    function cik () {
        alert("in cik");
        $("input").change(function() {
           alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Is there a catch here or is it something wrong with logic ?

Shortly;
i create some input elements with

```
HTMLelement.innerHTML = '<input type="text">'
```

after document become ready. So...jquery event handler need to be executed after a button pressed.

Comment: What's wrong with delegating event instead??? http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: don't bind events inside of user generated events..

Comment: @Kevin B : So all handlers should stay as global?

Comment: it doesn't have to be global, i don't understand what you mean by that. Bind the event at the same time you are creating the element.